# Let F an absolutely irreducible faithful representation of degree $n$. Let $G'$ a subgroup of $Z(G)$ then $|G:Z(G)|=n^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let F an absolutely irreducible faithful representation of degree $n$. Let $G'$ a subgroup of $Z(G)$ then $|G:Z(G)|=n^2$

I think i've almost done it.

$F$ is faithful and absolutely irreducible, then i've observed that $Z=Z(G)$ is abelian and then every character is linear. I've obtained that $\chi$, the character associated to $F$, has the propriety that $\chi_Z=\chi(1)\cdot \lambda$ with some $\lambda\in Lin Z(G)$. Therefore $G/Z(G)$ is indeed abelian, since $G'\subseteq Z(G)$, then has got only linear characters.

Then I observe that $\forall \psi\in Irr(G/Z(G))$ $$\langle\lambda^G, \chi \cdot \psi\rangle=\langle\lambda, (\chi)_Z\cdot(\psi)_Z\rangle=\langle\lambda, \chi_Z\rangle=\langle\lambda, \lambda\cdot\chi(1)\rangle=\chi (1)$$

Then I've observe that, since $F$ is absolutely irreducible and faithful then for any field $k$, $kG\cong Mat(n,k)$. Then the only irreducible character of degree $n$ is $\chi$ and then $\lambda^G=\chi(1)\chi$. (Not really sure of that).

Then clearly $\lambda^G(1)=|G:Z(G)|=\chi(1)^2=n^2$.

My doubt is that seem to be useless the info that $G'\subseteq Z(G)$. Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: But you did use that info in your argument that all characters of $G/Z(G)$ were linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that $\chi$ vanishes outside $Z(G)$. So let $g \in G - Z(G)$, then there exists an $x \in G$ with $g^{-1}x^{-1}gx \neq 1$. Since $G' \subseteq Z(G)$ we have $z=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx \in Z(G)$. Hence (from the lemma of Schur) $F(z)=\epsilon I$, with $\epsilon \neq 1$, a root of unity (if $\epsilon=1$ then $z \in ker(F)=1$, since $F$ is assumed to be faithful). So, $F(gz)=F(g)F(z)=\epsilon F(g)$, implying $\chi(gz)=\epsilon \chi(g)$. On the other hand, $F(gz)=F(x^{-1}gx)=F(g)$, so $\chi(gz)=\chi(g)$. Since $\epsilon \neq 1$, we must have $\chi(g)=0$. Hence, $1=[\chi,\chi]=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|\chi(g)|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}(\sum_{g \in Z(G)}|\chi(g)|^2+\sum_{g \in G-Z(G)}|\chi(g)|^2)=\frac{1}{|G|}(\sum_{g \in Z(G)}|\epsilon_g\chi(1)|^2+0)=\frac{|Z(G)| \cdot \chi(1)^2}{|G|}.$

Comment: @Acuo95: if you deem my answer the right one please tick it as such.